# Inserting A Record To Lookup Table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I refer to the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846170/1753877) about how to insert a record into the `Users_Friends` lookup table in this type of relationship

[image]

The answer is :

```
var user = db.Users.Find(userID);
var friend = db.Friends.Find(friendID);
user.Friends.Add(friend);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, to me it seems like a lot of overhead to have to retrieve two objects from the database just to insert  a row comprising of just the two IDs that are already known to the application without the need for any queries.

Could we not just do a basic `INSERT` using `userID` and `friendID` as values (or pass them to a stored procedure to do the same).

As I am new to Entity Framework, I'm unsure if there are any advantages to using the code above that would be missed with a direct SQL `INSERT`, or if there is a valid reason to avoid using direct SQL with Entity framework for inserts

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

first is if `User_Friends` has its own entity you can just populate a new user_friends with the id's and save changes.

The second is to create a New friend and user and attach them (something similar to this, may take some tweaking):

```
var friend = new Friend{Id = friendID};

var user = new User{Id = userID};

using (var context = new Context()) 
{ 
    context.Friends.Attach(friend); 
    user.Friends.Add(friend);

    context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

[Entity Framework Add and Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx)

The third is to use Context.Database and either execute sql command or sql query (depending) to execute arbitrary SQL against the database.

What I have found the easiest is to include `User_Friends` as its own EF entity and create a new one.  It makes adding to the union table very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a direct insert like:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"insert into Users_friends 
   (UserId, FriendId) values ({0}, {1})", userID, friendID);
```

I don't see an advantage first retrieving the values from db (except verifying both user and friend exists). However, in the above code there is no check if userID, friendID pair already exists which could be easily added to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is a lot needless overhead. In Entity Framework, it's enough to just pass a new instance of the class with the PK loaded:

```
var user = db.Users.Find(userID);
var friend = new Friend { Id = friendID };
user.Friends.Add(friend);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the bridge table as a model as well, like this

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public List<UserFriend> Friends { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
          Friends = new List<UserFriend>();
    }
}

public class Friend
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class UserFriend
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int FriendId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FriendId")]
    public Friend Friend { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create or get user friends like this

```
// add user friend
var userFriend = new UserFriend()
{
     UserId = userId,
     FriendId = friendId
};
db.UserFriends.Add(userFriend);
db.SaveChanges();


// get user friends
db.Users.Include("Friends").ToList();
```